# Returning the smallest integer in an arrayList in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I recently got asked in a interview to create an method where the following checks are to be made:

1. Code to check if ArrayList is null
2. Code to loop through ArrayList objects
3. Code to make sure object is an integer
4. Code to check if it is null, and if not then to compare it against a variable containing the smallest integer from the list and if smaller then
   overwrite it.
5. Return the smallest integer in the list.

So I created the following method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(2);
    list.Add(3);
    list.Add(4);
    list.Add(5);

    Program p = new Program();
    p.Min(list);            
}

private int? Min(ArrayList list)
{
    int value;                                         
    //Code to check if ArrayList is null
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
       string minValue = GetMinValue(list).ToString();

       //Code to loop through ArrayList objects
       for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
       {                    
           //Code to make sure object is an integer
           //Code to check if it is null, and if not to compare it against a variable containing the
           //smallest integer from the list and if smaller overwrite it.
           if (Int32.TryParse(i.ToString(), out value) || i.ToString() != string.Empty)
           {
               if (Convert.ToInt32(list[i]) < Convert.ToInt32(minValue))
               {
                   minValue = list[i];
               }
           }
         }
       }            
       return Convert.ToInt32(GetMinValue(list));
}

public static object GetMinValue(ArrayList arrList)
{
       ArrayList sortArrayList = arrList;
       sortArrayList.Sort();
       return sortArrayList[0];
}
```

I think the above is somewhat correct, however am not entirely sure about 4?

Comment: Shouldn't it be : minValue = list[i];

Comment: Oops corrected that @jdweng thanks

Comment: Did I solve your issue?

Comment: Why have I been down voted?

Comment: Don't know but you code won;'t always work.   For the algorithm to always work you need to initialize the variable 'value' to a number in the list. Initializing value to zero when the minimum is 5 the code doesn't work.

Comment: Don't work there. It's not okay to use ArrayList anymore. Even if you don't know the type, use `List<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

I think The following logic may help you. It is simpler than the current and are using [`int.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) for parsing, which is better than `Convert.To..()` and `int.Parse()` Since it has some internal error handling and hence it will will not throw any exception for invalid input. If the input is invalid then it gives `0` to the out variable and returns `false`, From that we can assume the conversion failed.  See the code for this:

```
var arrayMin = listOfInt;
int currentNum = 0;
int yourNum = int.MaxValue;
bool isSuccess = true;
foreach (var item in listOfInt)
{
    if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out currentNum) && currentNum <= yourNum)
    {
        yourNum = currentNum;
    }
    else
    {
        isSuccess = false;
        break;
    }              
}
if(isSuccess)
    Console.WriteLine("Minimum Number in the array is {0}",yourNum);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input element found");
```

Comment: Shouldn't int `minNum = int.MaxValue;` be `int minNum = int.MinValue;`?

Comment: @Kevin : Good thinking but will not give the expected output

Comment: There is an issue with the solution, if the array list contains a string item `"0"` then it will return a invalid input element found. However the function `int.TryParse` should parse it? Any suggestions

Comment: @Kevin: Have you tested that? And have you read the Link associated with the the `int.TryParse`? It will not check for `0` will check for the return value indicating the conversion status

Comment: I didn't notice the link for the `Int.TryParse'. So it seems the conversion will fail. What else do you suggest to use for conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Simplistic version:

```
private int? Min(ArrayList list)
{
    if (list == null || list.Count == 0) return null;
    return list.Cast<int>().Min();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however there is an issue if the list contains a string int value like `"0"`. I get a `Cast is invalid` exception.